# nginx doesn't parse php request

Tags: php, nginx

env:
ubuntu 9.10 /
use gotdeb source /
php version 5.3.1 /
php5-fpm installed /

php5-fpm is running , and listening 9000 port test by 2 commands below

```
pgrep php5-fpm
telnet localhost 9000
```

however if I visit from anthor computer in LAN ,using this address

```
http://192.168.1.103/index.php
```

the browser ask me to save this index.php , but if visit index.php , everything goes well

sites-enabled/default file content
env:
ubuntu 9.10 /
use gotdeb source /
php version 5.3.1 /
php5-fpm installed /

php5-fpm is running , and listening 9000 port test by 2 commands below

```
pgrep php5-fpm
telnet localhost 9000
```

however if I visit from anthor computer in LAN ,using this address

```
http://192.168.1.103/index.php
```

the browser ask me to save this index.php , but if visit index.html , everything goes well

sites-enabled/default file content

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000
    fastcgi_index index.php
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name
    include fastcgi_params
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A common pitfall is when your code is using short open tags `<?` instead of `<?php` and it's not enabled in php.ini on a fresh install so it won't get parsed.

To enable it set `short_open_tag=On`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to set your website's index.

You can see a full example [on nginx's official wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample), but here's the relevant part:

```
location / {
  index    index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

As you see, the virtual host needs to know it's supposed to process *index.php* when accessing the website via it's root dir (i.e. http://domain.com/ or http://domain.com/site/), with no file specified.

Answer (score 0):

1. I do have an index:

   ```
   location / {
       index index.php;
   }
   ```
2. I am not using `<?` PHP tags.