# How to use Super Global PHP variables inside JS file

Tags: javascript, php, global-variables

In my JavaScript file I've if statement and some code inside it. And I'm trying to use super global variable inside js function.

Here is the PHP code embedded inside JavaScript function:

```
if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
    window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>');
}
```

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable stands for 3-parametr of js function.

One more thing: When I write this code inside my somefile.php it's working fine. But I'm gonna put this partition of code inside external js file and include it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have PHP parse it - appending .php at the end of the filename, if you're using apache - it should be fine. You can load javascript files that end in PHP `<script src="test.js.php" />`.

Comment: I'm using Nginx and I tried append js file end of my php file. But it's still not working

Comment: But it's the other way around.. append .php at the end of your .js file. E.g. `somefile.js.php`

Comment: You mean including php file inside js file?

Comment: Yes, like you have in your question. PHP will be parsed by the server, JS will be parsed by the browser.

Comment: I've done as you said. But nothing changed. When I inspect browser it comes error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: Then, Nginx is not parsing the PHP file. I'm not an expert on Nginx, check this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394967/nginx-doesnt-parse-php-request

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate your help )